# Unable to see default android emoji in textview of my android app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-adapter, android-keypad, android-adapterview

I am developing a text messaging android app and when I am sending a text message with android keyboard emoji and recieving in another android mobile it is showing ?? (double Question mark). 
How can I able to see that emoji in my textview?

Like as below I am appending that text message

```
holder.chatText.setText(tempValues.getMessageText()+" \n ");
```

and sending that message to server as below

```
 public class SyncPendingMessageToServer extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //doShowLoading("Please Wait");
    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        if(Config.isInternetOn(getApplicationContext())  && loginUserInfoId == "") {
            List<ChatMessage> allChatMessage = db.getAllMessage();
            for (ChatMessage chatMessage : allChatMessage) {

                if (chatMessage.getIsPending() == 1 && chatMessage.getMediaMIMEType().isEmpty()) {
                    String msgText = chatMessage.getMessageText();

                    HttpClient myClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost myConnection = new HttpPost(Config.HOST_NAME + "/AndroidApp/SendMessage");

                    try {
                        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("messageText", msgText));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("senderUserInfoId", chatMessage.getSenderUserInfoId()));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("recieverUserInfoId", chatMessage.getReceiverUserInfoId()));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("messageThreadId", chatMessage.getOriginalMsgThreadId()));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("url", ""));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fileType", ""));

                        if(chatMessage.getIsPendingToUpdate() == 0) {
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("msgType", ""));
                        }
                        if(chatMessage.getIsPendingToUpdate() == 1) {
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("msgType", "GROUP"));
                        }

                        myConnection.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                        myClient.execute(myConnection);

                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message sending Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        //e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        //e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            db.updateSyncedMessage();
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean status) {
        //do whatever you want in this method
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new SyncPendingMessageToServer().execute();
            }
        }, 200);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Android has support of emoji starting from 4.4. Some vendors built-in emoji in previous versions of Android, but you can't rely on it.
The best choice would be to use some library which allows to show emoji in text views, [emojicon](https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon) is one of them.

Comment: This answer would be more helpful if you could link to some documentation or other source explaining what you mean by "support of emoji". There are many things that can be done with emoji. Do you mean Android supports *showing emoji in text views* starting from 4.4?

Answer (score 0):

this is a good openSource for you 
https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon
hope it helps..it allows you to display smileys in textView